# Sorting / showing entries by author in control panel

Tags: control-panel, author

Is there a way when you are viewing entries via the Content > Edit section to pull back all entries by author?

Currently if I sort the entries by Author I guess it is using the ID to sort by and not the Author Name. We have over 8000 members so for the editor to try and find one is going to be a lengthy exercise.

Answer (score 2):

Sadly the default EE Edit screen does not allow you to  easily sort by authors but this is a great use case for [Zenbu](http://devot-ee.com/add-ons/zenbu). Zenbu allows the admin to filter the content easily by author or even custom field data.